# Perform segue on completion of web service call Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, segue

I am trying to perform a segue on successful login in swift 3. Once my web service returns success message I want to perform segue. I am trying the same in the following manner:

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
       print("Login successful")
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTimerPage", sender: self)
})
```

My log is printing fine.
Please help me with this. I am new to web services.

Comment: Is "Login Successful" is printing, in console ?

Comment: What happens when this code runs?  Why are you using sync instead of async?

Comment: Yes login successful is printing in console

Comment: I tried async too

Comment: Please check you are setting identifier properly.

Comment: yes i have done that too

Comment: where's your code for network call / webservice call.  where you have added the above  code , after getting data from the service call add the above code . It will work

Comment: I think it's your storyboard segue string, if you perform segue inside the webservice success callback block, the segue should run correctly.

Comment: @Dia check my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
 DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
       print("Login successful")
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTimerPage", sender: self)
})

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "goToTimerPage" {
//present your view controller or do some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way for navigation.

Setup your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like this way.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    let storyboard :UIStoryboard

    if  UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad{

        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main_iPad", bundle: nil)
    }
    else{
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    }


    let navigationController:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController

    let objLoginViewController:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID_LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

    navigationController.viewControllers = [objLoginViewController]


    if self.window != nil {
        self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    }



    return true
}
```

Call this function once get successful response.

```
self.redirectToNewViewcontroller()
```

Code for redirectToNewViewcontroller function

```
func redirectToNewViewcontroller()
{
    let objNewViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID_NewViewController") as? NewViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objNewViewController!, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply make sure you embed your view controller in a navigation controller
the source view controller not the destination view controller